# Cloth physics not rendering correctly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, cloth-simulation

I'm working on a Happy Birthday clip (200 frames), and I've got balloons floating up in the background with strings attached that have cloth physics so they'll float around like a string would. Everything looks fine in the viewport, but while rendering the animation, the strings start detaching from the balloons and floating below them not connected to anything.

You can see at the bottom of the first picture that the string has become detached.

[image: Example of what's happening.]

[image: What it should look like.]

Now, if I stop the animation render and restart it from where it left off, it'll fix the problem... for that one frame. And then the next one will be messed up again. And it's not just for those 2 balloons, it's for all 11 of them. So it's not like I can just suck it up and only manually render the frames these balloons are in.

Does manually rendering 200 frames sound like a nightmare to anyone else?

I'm relatively new to blender, so I can't tell if I did something wrong or if my computer just can't handle this render. I'm rocking a lonely GTX 1070, so I'm sure that might be a possibility.

I saw a lot of other cloth physics problems being caused by the object having a sub modifier, but none of these have any modifiers beyond the cloth physics. So that's not it. I forgot to adjust the color settings before I started rendering, so I have to start over regardless. If no one can help, I guess I'll try removing the cloth physics.

I've never used the cloth physics before, but I literally changed no settings, so I'm not sure how I could have screwed it up. I used a vertex group on each of them at the top of the strings for the shape setting, and that was it. I knew it couldn't be so easy lol.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you joined the object only, you need to merge them. You can do this by using [`Boolean Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html). Use *Union* to merge them together so they remain connected.

---